# Postfix: Require user authentication when submitting but not when receiving a relay

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta

I'm trying to determine the correct access permissions in Postfix configuration to require user authentication for all direct submissions (i.e. from applications sending an email to a user), but not require authentication when receiving email from other MTAs - gmail, etc.

I tried this:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
```

But this allows **unauthenticated** direct submissions to any user in a allowed destination.

I also tried:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated reject
```

But that prevents relays to my server (from gmail) since gmail doesn't have auth creds.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` instead of `smtpd_client_restrictions`... and use `check_recipient_access` to look up allowed local users/aliases.

Working config:

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_recipients permit_sasl_authenticated reject`